# Migrate a Column into Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns 'ID, LIST_OF_VALUES'.
Example data is:

```
ID| LIST_OF_VALUES
--+----------------------------
1 | firstval-secondval-thirdval
2 | val1-val2
3 | val10-val20-val30
4 | singleval
```

I would like to select the data like this:

```
ID|   VAL1   |   VAL2    |   VAL3
--+----------+-----------+-------
1 | firstval | secondval | thirdval
2 | val1     | val2      | NULL
3 | val10    | val20     | val30
4 | singlval | NULL      | NULL
```

I am aware of the STRING_SPLIT function. I have tried using it in various ways with Cross Apply, but I can't seem to get the result I want.

I know I can do this using a mess of SUBSTR/INDEX, but I am just curious if STRING_SPLIT offers a more elegant solution.

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple and very efficient and scalable way would be to use an [ordinal splitter](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) such as dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (or dbo.DelimitedSplitN4K (for nchar/nvarchar).  Then the query would be something like this

dbo.DelimitedSplit8K tvf

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit8K
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l;
```

Query

```
select t.id,
       max(case when ds.ItemNumber=1 then ds.Item end) as val1,
       max(case when ds.ItemNumber=2 then ds.Item end) as val2,
       max(case when ds.ItemNumber=3 then ds.Item end) as val3
from tTable t
     cross apply
     dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.LIST_OF_VALUES, '-') ds
group by t.id
order by t.id;
```

[EDIT] Here is an alternate method which produces the same output but does not use the DelimitedSplit8K function.  This is the same approach as Gordon's but with an outer GROUP BY clause.

```
;with charindex_split_cte(id, Item, ItemNumber) as (
    select t.id, sp.value,
           row_number() over (order by charindex('-' + sp.value + '-', '-' + t.list_of_values + '-'))
    from tTable t
         cross apply string_split(t.list_of_values, '-') sp)
select id,
       max(case when ItemNumber=1 then Item end) as val1,
       max(case when ItemNumber=2 then Item end) as val2,
       max(case when ItemNumber=3 then Item end) as val3
from charindex_split_cte
group by id
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another option

**Example of XML Option**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,Val1 = tmpXML.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')
      ,Val2 = tmpXML.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
      ,Val3 = tmpXML.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
 from YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( Cast('<x>' + replace([LIST_OF_VALUES],'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) ) ) B(tmpXML)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Val1        Val2        Val3
1   firstval    secondval   thirdval
2   val1        val2        NULL
3   val10       val20       val30
4   singleval   NULL        NULL
```

**Example of JSON Option - as suggested by @PanagiotisKanavos if 2016+**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Val1 = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')
      ,Val2 = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
      ,Val3 = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]')
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(replace([LIST_OF_VALUES],'"','\"'),'-','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

Comment: I suspect using JSON would be faster.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just for fun, I added the JSON

Comment: Ok, atleast I know I am not losing my mind. This is a pretty clean approach. Thank you. I'll give it a day, then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @sheamus Always happy to help

Comment: I ended up using a variation of the JSON method. I used CONCAT and didn't worry about replacing the quotes, as I know my data set does not use it.  I put this in a function, then used Cross Apply to get the result from the function so that I could map the three values in my main query.

Comment: @sheamus Well done!   Escaping the quotes is just a fail-safe.   The concat() doesn't buy you anything but it makes for prettier code.   Here is my generic table-valued function  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3aa8808fe8e1de251f270986ab91c178

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have duplicates, you can use it . . . but it is not trivial:

```
select t.*, s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as val1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as val2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as val3
      from (select s.value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex('-' + value + '-', '-' + t.list_of_values + '-') as seqnum
            from string_split(t.list_of_values, '-') s
           ) s
     ) s;
```

Unfortunately, `string_split()` doesn't provide the ordering.  This recreates it using `charindex()`.

Comment: I do have duplicates... this is close.

Comment: @sheamus . . . There are no duplicates in the sample data in the question.